# Referencing all Models at once in a Controller?

Tags: laravel

```
use App\Http\Models\CarModel;
..
..
..
```

The relevant models are used in a controller file as mentioned above

Is it possible to, like have a template kind of a thing to include all those models in a project and then import only that in a controller (Assuming all models have unique names)?

Is this practical ?

Are there any performance issues ?

Comment: Why you need all model in single controller ? it will be terrible practice when there are  large number of models

Comment: @SagarGautam Then i don't want to worry about inserting them time to time. Why you said as terrible practice? Is it because anything related to performance

Comment: It's not the best practice. If you want to skip multiple lines you can use something `use App\Http\Model\{User,Article,AnyModel};`

Comment: Usually, your IDE takes care of importing required classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting your model based on the request, you can do something like this instead of importing all the models:

```
$model = 'App\\'.$request->get('model');
```

Then:

```
$data = $model::where(...
```